# How to use the bean created in the test to run an application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-jdbc, spring-boot-test

I am writing test for an application where DataSource is created as a Bean when connecting to the DB2 Database. For the test I would like to use an in-memory H2 Database and call the main method to run the application. I have created a bean for the Datasource with H2 Database in the test folder. However when I call the main method, the control is always going to the original application and the Bean with the DB2 database is always created. How can I make use of the bean with H2 database in the application? The config class that I have written in the test is never called and so the bean with H2 Database is never created.

I have the config class in the test folder that is imported later in the test file.

```
@TestConfiguration
@AutoConfiguration
public class H2Test {


@Primary
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean

public Datasource getH2bean() {
JdbcDataSource jdbcDataSource=new JdbcDataSource();
jdbcDataSource.setURL(<<Url to the H2 in-memory Database>>);
//further code
return jdbcDataSource;
}
}
```

I want the bean of datasource above (`getH2bean`) to be used while running the complete application as I want to call the main method of the application.

The test file from where I call the main method is as below-

```
@SpringBootTest(classes={H2Test.class})
@ContectConfiguration(classes ={H2Test.class})
public class mainTest{


@Test
public void testMain() throws Exception{

A a=new A();
Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(()-> a.main());
//call the main method of the application here
}
}
```

How to use the `getH2bean()` in the original application in this context?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't maintained separete configurations for dev and test setup of your application. This is basically maintaining dedicated spring profiles.

In spring-boot, you can create an `application.properties` containing db config of your actual database, lets say postgre sql

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password= dummypwd
# some more postgres specific properties
```

and `application-test.properties` containing your H2 database config.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
# some more H2 specific properties
```

And then in your Test class, you can use `@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")` annotation to activate the corresponding profile, and load the configurations associated with it.

See [ActiveProfiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html) for further details

Eg

```
@SpringBootTest(classes={H2Test.class})
@ContectConfiguration(classes ={H2Test.class})
@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")
public class mainTest{


@Test
public void testMain() throws Exception{

A a=new A();
Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(()-> a.main());
//call the main method of the application here
}
}
```

Please note:
You'll may need to refactor your first line in `mainTest` class to `@SpringBootTest(classes = YourApplication.class)`  where `YourApplication.class` is your Spring-Boot Application's main class

Comment: Hello, thanks for your inputs! I have created the application-test.properties but still the DB2 bean is getting created. I want the H2 DB bean to do the job for me but unfortunately it is not the case. I also have created @Activeprofile("test")

Comment: Hello Jeet, Will it be possible for you to share your code in a git repo, i can then give it a try, replicating the issue.